# Array Collection: The mapping association are incosistent with each other

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, arraycollection

I have an User entity and a mission entity, that are associated

In the profiler of symfony i get two errors.

For the class Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\User I get:

```
The mappings Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\User#missions and Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\Mission#users are incosistent with each other.
```

For the class Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\Mission I get:

```
The association Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\Mission#users refers to the inverse side field Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\User#users which does not exist.
```

I tried to solve by myself reading [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing) but I could't.

My mission entity is:

class Mission {

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="users")
     */
    protected $users;

    public function __construct(){
        $this -> users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

        /**
     * Add users
     *
     * @param \Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\User $users
     * @return Mission
     */
    public function addUser(\Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\User $users)
    {
        $this->users[] = $users;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove users
     *
     * @param \Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\User $users
     */
    public function removeUser(\Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\User $users)
    {
        $this->users->removeElement($users);
    }

    /**
     * Get users
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }
//...
}
```

And my user entity:

```
abstract class User extends BaseUser
{

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\Mission", mappedBy="users")
     */
    protected $missions;    
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this -> missions = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    /**
     * Add missions
     *
     * @param \Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\Mission $missions
     * @return User
     */
    public function addMission(\Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\Mission $missions)
    {
        $this->missions[] = $missions;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove missions
     *
     * @param \Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\Mission $missions
     */
    public function removeMission(\Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\Mission $missions)
    {
        $this->missions->removeElement($missions);
    }

    /**
     * Get missions
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getMission()
    {
        return $this->missions;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong annotation in the `users` property in `Mission` class. It should be:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="missions")
 */
protected $users;
```